# Do polarized prescription lens also protect against UV?

Tags: uv-protection, sunglasses

My optometrist assures me that all polarized prescription lens will now also assure 100% UV protection.  Is this true and if not how can I insure that I’m getting optimum UV protection from new prescription lens?

Comment: @JohnHughes That one is polarized, this one is polarized **prescription** lenses. Would being prescription make enough of a difference?

Comment: I think it doesn't make enough difference because prescription has to do with the means of purchase, not the glasses themselves. Also, I would suggest that questions of the form "is my doctor correct about the thing he's certified in" are not appropriate for the site (although I'd be happy to discuss!)

Comment: I agree with John here. To me questions putting a dr.s advice on their field against ours are silly for this site.

Comment: This needs a geographical area. I doubt that the same rules apply in China and the US.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate. Lenses are made of different materials than glasses. Voting to leave open.

Comment: @JanDoggen - ambigous English I think, lenses as in contacts the lens in the pair of glasses? Also to be aware of, whats the prescription, some glasses come with bifocals etc. Glass in general has better UV protection (uvb and some uva eg windscreens) I believe than plastic, so I'd imagine prescription glasses would give more UV protection. Regarding the question, quick google > https://www.framesdirect.com/blog/what-uv-protection-and-how-do-uv-sunglasses-help see last couple of paragrpahs

Comment: @Fran So please tell us if you mean lenses for glasses or contact lenses. BTW if the first, you can close (vote) your own question as a duplicate.

Comment: Note that "UV protection" is ambiguous. What UV ranges should we/they protect for?

Comment: I assumed, since it's tagged "sunglasses", that this was not referring to contact lenses. If it's about contacts though, I actually think it is a *very* good question and definitely not a duplicate, and I'll un-vtc.